# Firefox: Inspect javascript which is modifying DOM

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, web-deployment

If you visit this page https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/aapl/earnings you will notice that the part "Earnings announcement* for AAPL: Jan 28, 2020" is dynamically loaded after the pageload.

So it's dynamically inserted by some Javascript.
I'm wondering how to find out which javascript is being run and modifying this element. I'm hoping to find out whether this data is coming from some sort of AJAX request, so maybe I can request this data via some HTTP Request programmatically.

But I'm struggling to find the corresponding JS code.
Is there any way with Firefox Webdevelopers Tools (Built-in into Firefox using F12?) to find it? Via Google I saw that there's an option "Breakpoint on DOM modification" but it's not available in my Firefox 60 for me. So I'm not sure how to dig into it and I want to avoid to search all js code of that page manually.

Thanks!

**EDIT**
Found the answer to where the data is coming from now via inspecting of network-transfers in Firefox, which showed me that this Xhr request is made to https://api.nasdaq.com/api/analyst/AAPL/earnings-date which returns a JSON dataobject.

But still the original question about checking javascripts modifying elements remains. Thanks

Comment: I'm not immediately seeing a way in Firefox. It's easy in Chrome/Chromium/Brave, if you want to use one of those: Right-click the element, choose Inspect, and then when the DOM inspector comes up, right-click the tag for the element and choose "Break on > subtree modications." Later when you want to stop doing that, remove that DOM Breakpoint (right-hand pane in devtools).

Comment: But is this setting persistent? Because I think you will never be fast enough after page reload to set the "viewpoint" on a DOM element before the element is already modified.

Comment: Yes, it is. :-) If you hit reload, the breakpoint remains (like other breakpoints) until you remove it. (I think they use a selector or similar under the covers. Certainly it's shown as a selector.) It's not perfect, but...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The process for setting/clearing a breakpoint on DOM modification in Firefox could be described with exactly the same words which you used to describe it for Chrome (with the exception that it's "Inspect Element (Q)", not "Inspect", in the page's right-click context menu). I'm unsure why you were unable to find it. Are we seeing different things? On different versions of FF?

Comment: @Makyen - Yup, different versions. :-) I forgot my Linux distro tends to lag behind on Firefox, I was using v66. Just checked v72 and I see it. Sadly, it doesn't retain the breakpoint when you refresh, though.

Comment: Well, thanks, didn't know it's only available since such a "new" version. I'm still on v68 and it's not available there. My corporate company seems to also lag behind with distributing updates :D So.... thanks, at least I know now how to find it in Chrome. I'll give it a try.